# How to make a matrix with a stroke

Tags: math-mode, lyx

[image: Example]

I can only insert matrix without the stroke.

Comment: I'm not sure this should be marked as a duplicate since the question has the tag "lyx". Perhaps the question should be edited to specify that the OP is looking for a solution that is native to LyX. The other answers could be adapted to be used in LyX by using LyX's TeX box (Insert > TeX Code) and also adding relevant code to the LaTeX preamble in Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble. Then it will work, but LyX will not show it in WYSIWYM. It can show it in WYSIWYG if you wrap the TeX Box in Insert > Preview (if preview is on in Tools > Preferences).

Comment: @scottkosty I voted to reopen, but apparently the gold tag badge works both for opening and closing .. So the question is opened again, feel free to add an answer :)

Comment: Thanks for voting to reopen! Oh shoot, now I feel bad since I don't know an elegant "LyX way" to answer the question :). I scrolled through the Help > Math manual and don't see something like it. Perhaps ERT is the only solution.

Comment: Take a look at `nicematrix`.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to draw this type of matrix using LyX's GUI (and not using ERT) you must do it with `array` and not `pmatrix`. In LyX: 1) enter math mode (via `ctrl+M` or `ctrl+shift+M`), 2) press `Alt+M (` to add the parentheses, 3) type `\array` then space.

Now you should see the array menu at the bottom of the screen, there you can add rows and columns to the array.

[image]

After formatting the array to the desired size, right click on the column positioned to the left of the vertical bar you want to add, and press `Add Line to Right`.

[image]